# osmdroid map change orientation with animation

Tags: android, openstreetmap, android-mapview, osmdroid, android-orientation

I am using `MapView.setMapOrientation()` method for changing mapview's orientation. Now I want to add some animation while changing orientation. Can you suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from version 6.0.3  the controller supports orientation in animateTo, something like this (code not tested!)
reference: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1119

```
mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocation,mapView.getZoomLevelDouble(),null, (float) mapHeading);
```